# How to drop columns in those 2D numpy arrays that have more than N columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 different 2D numpy arrays, each having a different number of columns:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.randn(10, 5)
arr2 = np.random.randn(10, 6)
arr3 = np.random.randn(10, 4)
```

Now I want to merge these 3 2D arrays into a single 3D array:

```
myList = []
myList.append(arr1)
myList.append(arr2)
myList.append(arr3)

3darr = np.dstack(myList)
```

However, since the arrays have different number of columns, I get an error:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis
> must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has
> size 5 and the array at index 1 has size 6

How can I create a 3D array by taking the minimum number of columns across the 3 2D arrays? In other words, the minimum number of columns across the 3 2D arrays is equal to 4. Thus, I want to drop the columns after 4th in all 2D arrays that have more than 4 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope following could help.

```py
import numpy as np
a = []
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 5))
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 6))
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 4))
k = min([i.shape[1] for i in a])
out = np.zeros((a[0].shape[0], k, len(a)))
for ind in range(len(a)):
    out[:,:,i] = a[i][:,:k]
```

Comment: Hmm, what if the minimum number of columns, i.e. 4, is unknown?

Comment: just do a for loop and search for min of a[i].shape[1]

Comment: Ok, I have a code that find the minimum number of columns. But I still get an error:  `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: Just try `np.zeros(10, 4, 5)`. It does not work.

Comment: I edited that for the zeros, the shape must be in parenthesis

Comment: Check my last edit please it should do all you have required

Comment: Maybe you could help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743501/how-to-extend-dimensions-of-numpy-arrays