# How to extend dimensions of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = []
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 5))
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 6))
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 4))
```

I need to extend the number of columns till 10 in each array in the list `a`, so that I get `(10,10)` dimensional arrays inside the list `a`. The values of new columns should be filled out with `1`.

How can I do so?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @Ivan: Could you please clarify your ask? I provided examples of 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following

```py
import numpy as np
a = []
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 5))
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 6))
a.append(np.random.randn(10, 4))
out = np.ones((len(a), 10, 10))
for i in range(len(a)):
    out[i,:a[i].shape[0],:a[i].shape[1]] = a[i].copy()
```

contenation would add extra computational cost as it will copy the newly created ones matrices.

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

Comment: I havn't checked the code let me try it out Ill get back to you

Comment: can you test it again because its working for me - I guess you have used the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 10x10 array of ones, you can use this:

```py
my_array = np.ones((10,10))
print(my_array)
print(my_array.shape)
```

Otherwise, you can't change the shape of an [array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html) after it's already been created.

Comment: I don't need an array of ones. I want to extend the existing 2D arrays by adding new columns filled out with values equal to 1.

Comment: Ok thanks, I must have misunderstood what you're asking, because arrays can't be extended, you must create a new one altogether. Hopefully @Ivan answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

From a given tensor shaped `(10, i)`, you can complete it with `1`s to match a shape of `(10, 10)`. Using [`np.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) you can create a tensor of shape `(10, 10-i)`:

For the first element of `a`, this will look like:

```
>>> np.ones((10, 10-x.shape[1]))
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Then, combine the tensor and the ones with [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
>>> o = np.ones((10, 10-x.shape[1]))
>>> xo = np.concatenate((x, o), axis=1)

>>> xo.shape
(10, 10)
```

You get the desired result using a *list* comprehension on `a`:

```
>>> [np.concatenate((x, np.ones((10, 10-x.shape[1]))), 1) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a matrix of shape (10,10) and set it's first (10, n) members to your matrices. A working solution for your example:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    array = a[i]
    result = np.ones((10,10))
    result[:array.shape[0],:array.shape[1]] = array
    a[i] = result
```

Comment: I get error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,10) into shape (10,4)`